# Bootstrap: Resampling more observations than exist in original dataset

Tags: bootstrap, resampling, sampling-distribution

I want to resample an existing study with the primary aim of investigating how the empirical sampling distribution of a statistic varies with different sample sizes.

For example, if the original study has $N=100$ observations, I'd like to investigate the form of the empirical sampling distribution when $N=1000,~ 100,~ 50,~ 30,~ 10,~ 5$ observations, etc.

I expect this statistic to have an approximately Normal sampling distribution. I observe this for the original sample size and smaller, though obviously with fat tails for the smaller sample sizes.

For sample sizes larger than the original sample size, I am getting strange distribution shapes, somewhat normal looking but almost triangular. I am suspecting that this is due to resampling the same observations so many times, causing the distribution to become much more discrete.

As a result, I feel as though this approach is not valid. That is, I can only resample as many or fewer observations than the original study. Is this true? Is there a name for this phenomenon?

Are there any suggestions for alternative approaches that may be taken?